# richfaces tree collapse by clicking tree node

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

the default behaviour of richfaces tree will collapse by pressing "expand" (>) on the left hand side of the 'treenode name' . Is it possible to collapse the tree by pressing 'treenode name' instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see from this [example](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tree&skin=blueSky) there is a function called `toggle` in the `tree.js` 
Just start it when the user clicks the name.
 Or get the > element (for example with jQuery [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)) and use `click()` 
example: `$(".rf-trn-hnd").click()` - opens the whole tree